# Angular: Backend and Frontend in same project or seperate?

Tags: angular

lets assume I have a website for restaurants. I consider the front end as the website where the menu and its dishes are listed. Then I wan't to have a separate "backend" for the owner, so he can edit the menu. This applies for other features like reservation and orders too.

Im wondering what the best way to achieve this is. My first Idea was to create a separate angular project. The downside to this solution is that I would have to code some objects/models and services twice.

If I would have "backend" and "frontend" in the same project I could use the same services and objects but then the projects would get unnecessary big, because the regular user will only have access to the "front end". Also I can't use the same navigation for both.

The perfect way would be to have 2 separate angular projects that shave some services/objects. Is that maybe possible? Also what are other (dis)advantages for these two ways, I didn't noticed yet? How would you do it?

Comment: This isn't called a back-end but a back-office. And you can chose whatever you want, the question you should ask to your client is *do you want your back-office to be on the same URL as your website ?*

Comment: This is not backend.. and you should have it in the same project, since it is the same project. You should have admin panel which is your manager panel, which only authorized member get access too. Also, you should construct it in lazy module way, so no one without the access would load all the unnecessary pages.

Comment: Thank you guys, I knew it wasn't a backend but I didn't knew how to call it. Backoffice is a lot better. I guess I will do It in the same project and have a look at lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

On last WeAreDevelopers event in Vienna they have presentation for using Nrwl framework https://nrwl.io/ for this cases. I have try to use this and works nice, just like you said you will be able to write your own api. Beside that new angular cli support also this idea to you can have multiple projects that share some resources like services and classes but this is lite version comparing nrwl framework.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it!